# Sencha Touch: load ANSI JSON to store

Tags: javascript, json, sencha-touch-2

I have some issues to load a JSON-file from a server to a sencha touch store. You can find the json-file here: https://service.bmf.gv.at/finanzamtsliste.json

It's an ANSI file. After loading the file I get � instead of the German Umlaute.

I can't modify the json-file, because it's from a third party organisation.

Is it possible to load a ANSI-JSON-file to a sencha touch store with the right codec?

Thank you in advance!

```
Ext.define('myapp.store.app.finanzamt', {
alias: 'store.Finanzamt',
id: 'finanzamt',
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: ['myapp.model.app.finanzamtItem'],

config: {
    model: 'myapp.model.app.finanzamtItem',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        url: 'https://service.bmf.gv.at/Finanzamtsliste.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
```

Comment: if override mime type is available you could try that, change it to `application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1`